# Postgres - most efficient way to retrieve most recent record from a group

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

We have a table with a log of job executions that took place. This table can get quite large (say 100M+ rows), though it's certainly possible that we could regularly prune the tail to keep it small (say < 1M rows, enough history for diagnostics).

We want to find a reasonably optimal query that can find the last execution for each job type. Jobs run on different frequencies; some every second, and some once a week. There are a few hundred "types" of jobs we want to track (once unique configuration is taken into consideration.)

We've thought of a few options:

Option 1) Use a trigger to upsert to a most_recent_execution table, using `on conflict` on job_configuration_id to overwrite records of the same id. Upside: this would be a small table with just a few hundred rows; downside: enormous amount of bloat (and vacuuming) needed on the table, since there'd be a lot of updates.

Option 2) BRIN index on the main log table, by execution_date/id. Upside: would just work in the same table. Downside: we don't understand the semantics of multiple column BRIN indices.

Option 3) Conditional index on the main log table, which uses some multiple of the known frequency of the job as a date range restriction for the records which are indexed. Downside: possible wrestling with the query planner.

Option 4) Conditional index on the main log table, which uses a windowing function to include the top ranked record of each type in the index. Downside: again, possible wrestling with query planner.

Of course we will prototype and benchmark, but if anybody's done similar we'd welcome your ideas.

Comment: Table definition? Is it normalised to 3NF? Does it have multiple candidate keys?

Comment: Not a complete answer, but if you use the trigger and just restrict yourself to an index on the update-type then HOT should reduce bloat substantially if you pick a reasonable `fill_factor` for that small table.

Comment: What's wrong with just an index on your timestamp and job type? You show us a couple of (complex) options, but the easiest one is missing. Also missing is the EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE) from the SELECT statement that's selecting your results.

Comment: @RichardHuxton thanks, we'll look at HOT updates in combination with the trigger approach - wasn't aware of them. (https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/hot-updates-in-postgresql-for-better-performance/)

Comment: @FrankHeikens our concern with that approach is that the index would be larger than necessary (i.e. would rely on our tail pruning to keep it reasonably sized, and even then it would need to index scan to find rows in the range.) You're right that we need to experiment and rule it out though.

Comment: @fridgepolice: Table partitioning might help, it keeps the partitions and their indexes (relatively) small.

Comment: From what I see a basic index will do the trick. Even if it's a large index it will still be very fast. No need for convoluted solutions.

Comment: Do you have a compact list of job types (e.g. in a smaller table with FK into it), or does it need to be inferred from the large table itself?

Answer (score 0):

Partition the log table by time range. Have a b-tree index on `(job_type, execution_time)` on the last few partitions. Get the `UNION` of the queries on the last few partitions with `WHERE job_type = 42 ORDER BY execution_time DESC LIMIT 1` and take the latest one.

That should be fast as lightening and avoid a large index. Downside: index maintenance costs on each `INSERT`.